# Delete from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a page containing a database table with all the rows and columns.
What I am trying to do is to select all the rows I want and then delete them when I click on the button.

This is what I've done so far in the table.php page:

```
<?php 
include "config.php";  //connection to database 
incude "home.js"; 
$funcao="Select * from  palavras";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $funcao);
?>


 <button id="button_apaga" type="button" onclick="delete()" > DELETE </button>      

 <?php  if($result->num_rows > 0)  { ?>

  <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <th>IdPalavra</th>
          <th>Palavra</th>
          <th>Grau de Dificuldade</th>
          <th>Data</th>
          <th>Hora</th>
          <th>Selecionar</th>
      </tr>


    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

      <tr role="row">
        <td><?php echo $row['idpalavras']; ?></td>       
        <td><?php echo $row['palavra']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['graudificuldade']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['hora']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>   
      </table> 

    <?php }
    else{
        echo "0 resultados";
    } ?>
```

JavaScript Page (home.js):

```
function delete(id){
    var check = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    if(check.checked) {
        // sql query 
    }
```

My question is how can I do que sql query considering it's in a different page. Can I just open php and put the query inside?

Also how can I receive all the IDs from the selected rows to the function?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use AJAX. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: I also don't see an element with an id of `checkbox`, so I'm guessing this is pseudocode.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it by accident. No, it's not pseudocode @user3783243

Comment: Your `id="checkbox"` is not unique so it will not be specific to any particular element (unless your SQL only returns 1, in that case don't need the `while`). You could do `checkbox_<?php echo $id;?>` so they are each unique then use `this` to get the current `id` by removing the `checkbox_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use AJAX. For the purpose of condensing the code, I'm going to also incorporate jQuery into this solution. I am also going to change your checkbox to an individual button link for the sake of making this a bit less code. A solution to delete multiple at the same time could work similarly to this, but since you're using AJAX most likely this is going to be easier for your users.

Modify `table.php`

```
<?php 
include "config.php";  //connection to database 
incude "home.js"; 
$funcao="Select * from  palavras";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $funcao);
?>

 <?php  if($result->num_rows > 0)  { ?>

  <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <th>IdPalavra</th>
          <th>Palavra</th>
          <th>Grau de Dificuldade</th>
          <th>Data</th>
          <th>Hora</th>
          <th>Selecionar</th>
      </tr>


    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

      <tr role="row" class="palavras_row">
        <td><?php echo $row['idpalavras']; ?></td>       
        <td><?php echo $row['palavra']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['graudificuldade']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['hora']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="palavras_delete" data-id="<?php echo $row['idpalavras']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>   
      </table> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.3.1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.palavras_row a.palavras_delete', function() {
        var _id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var _row = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php',
            data: {
                idpalavras: _id
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(__resp) {
                if (__resp.success) {
                    _row.remove(); // Deletes the row from the table
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Create a new file in the same folder as your `table.php` and name it `delete.php`

```
<?php
$idpalavras = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'idpalavras', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$success = false;
if ($idpalavras) {
    include "config.php";  //connection to database 
    $funcao="delete from palavras where idpalavras = " . $idpalavras;
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $funcao);
    $success = true;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('success' => $success));
```

The solution above sends a simple command to your PHP backend where the delete query can be run by PHP. You cannot run a mysql command directly from javascript since that is frontend code.

This code is a functional solution, but it is abbreviated; a more complete solution would have more detailed handling of potential errors (either via AJAX or processing your delete query). It should also have some security on your `delete.php` to make sure unauthorized users aren't able to delete records without the proper permission to do so.

Comment: You recommend `filter_input` over parameterized queries?

Comment: A combination of both is never a terrible idea, but you should always use `filter_input` for querying content that could potentially be manipulated by a malicious user.